# Skip a word, print the next one

Tags: java, arrays, string

I need to take words from the command line, save them into an array, and then print out the words like so:

```
input: asdf jkl qwerty dfs

output: - jkl qwerty dfs
       asdf - qwerty dfs
      asdf jkl - qwerty dfs
      asdf jkl qwerty -
```

Also, if the user provides only 2 words, I should achieve the same results. I do not understand how I would do this when the amount of arguments given can be different every time.
Here is what I have attempted:

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
{
String input1 = args[0];
String input2 = args[1];
String input3 = args[2];
String input4 = args[3];

String[] input = new String[4];
}

public static void printExceptOne(String[] exception, int x)
{
System.out.print("-");
System.out.print(" "+exception[1]);
System.out.print(" "+exception[2]);
System.out.println(" "+exception[3]);
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 7):

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printExceptOne(args);
    }

    private static void printExceptOne(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < args.length; j++) {
                String output = j == i ? "-" : args[j];
                // adjust spaces however you like
                System.out.print(" " + output);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

**Actual Test**

Input

```
asdf jkl qwerty dfs
```

Output

```
 - jkl qwerty dfs
 asdf - qwerty dfs
 asdf jkl - dfs
 asdf jkl qwerty -
```

Note: I assume the 3rd row of your expected output is incorrect.
You have it as

```
[asdf jkl - qwerty dfs]
```

Comment: Note that the use of turnary operators is sometimes frowned upon, due to readability issues.

Comment: @Matthew interesting to know - I didn't know that. Personally, on the contrary, I find them quite succinct for simple conditions. Chaining several of them does make them difficult for me.

Comment: How would i achieve the same results, but backwards? for example

Comment: - qwerty jkl asdf, dfs - jkl asdf, etc.

Comment: @inda1 You should try that yourself; that is the best way to learn. It is a very simple modification of the code in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Useful tools:

- `for(initializer, condition, what to do after each iteration) what to do`
  provide loop
- `if (condition) what to do`
  do `what to do` only when `condition` is `true`.

Possible implementation:

```
class Sample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // iterate for each rows
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
        {
            // iterate for wach words
            for (int j = 0; j < args.length; j++)
            {
                // print space for second words or later
                if (j > 0)
                {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                // determine what should be printed
                String toPrint = args[j];
                if (i == j)
                {
                    toPrint = "-";
                }
                // print it
                System.out.print(toPrint);
            }
            // proceed to next row
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use a nested loop. The loop will iterate through the values `i=`0 through the number of elements in the array, and the nested loop will print out all values not indexed at `i`.

```
public static void printExcept(String[] exception) {
    for(int i = 0; i < exception.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < exception.length; j++) {
            if( j != i ) {
                // Print elements that aren't at exception[i]
                System.out.print(exception[j]);
            } else {
                // Don't print elements at exception[i]
                System.out.println(" - ");
            }
        }
        // Move to next line
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

You have no need for the second parameter (at least from what I understood from your problem statement).

Read more about loops here:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm

Comment: Your idea is right a good old for loop will do the trick. But he wants a different output. Your method will output something unrelated to the logics of his question

Comment: @Theo Thanks for the heads up!